# Pycharm - Add keymap to save a plot from SciView

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to add a Keymap to save plots from SciView? I searched the short-cuts in the Keymap window but didn't find the option to do this.

I want to be able to access via a short-cut the `Save as File` option from the context menu of each plot instead of right-clicking the plot list for every plot I want to save.